# PHP bug or logic error?

Tags: php, mysql

So here is my problem. I have a 2 tables. One for the Product details and One for the Product quantity.

In the product details there is a field Status it should be available or Not Available. Then in the Product quantity table there is a qtyleft meaning the quantity available for the product. Now the problem is i put 0 on quantity on 4 products meaning no quantity left and it should echo "Item is out of stock". It works but on 1 item only. I can't figure this out because I analyze everything and i think there is no problem. Is this a bug or what?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        include('config.php');

        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM athan_products WHERE product_id = $id");
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $resultq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE product_id LIKE '%".$id."%'");
                //$resultq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE product_id LIKE =$id");
                while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultq))
                    { 
                        $qwerty=$rows['qtyleft'];
                    }       
                if ($qwerty !=0){           
                    echo '<tr>';
                    //echo '<td>'.$row3['product_size_name'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row3['price'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row3['description'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.'<input name="but" type="image" value="'.$row3['id'].'" src="images/button.png"  onclick="return myFunction()" />'.'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                else
                    {
                        echo '<tr>';
                        //echo '<td>'.$row3['product_size_name'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td align="center">'.'<h2>'.'Item is out of stock!'.'</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                        //echo '<td>'.'<h1>'.'"not available"'.'</h1>'.'</td>';
                    }
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Too much of code.Can you just post the code relevant to your question ?

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Chances are it's a logic error but the relevant PHP is obscured in a lot of irrelevant markup.  I did notice you're using mysql_* functions and are putting user input directly into queries though.  The former is bad because mysql_* is deprecated, and the latter is bad because it opens you up to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` in the second query instead of `=`.

Comment: i think you should be trying by changing name of input tag to array like this `<input name="but[]" `

Comment: Why do you have a `while` loop for the results of the first query? Can there be more than one product with the same ID?

Comment: oh i see. i change the second query and it echo what i want but it puts error in line 12 16. thank you for telling me sir @Barmar

Comment: One product cannot have the same id sir

Comment: So why do you need a `while` loop? Also, can there be multiple `inventory` records with the same `product_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I review your code, I think there is not any such error but you need to change you query.

```
$resultq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE product_id LIKE '%".$id."%'");
```

Into this which is given below.

```
$resultq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE product_id='".$id."'");
```

Hope you will solve your issue.

Thanks.

Comment: oh my! My pleasure sir this one save my day (y)